# Container not found in docker compose host network mode

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to create a `docker-compose` that would set up containers for `Postgres` and backend. I want the simplest option so I decided to just start them with `network_mode: host`. To start out I wanted to start the DB (`postgres`) and try to connect to it but I can't. Here is the compose:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=nameDb
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dev
      - POSTGRES_USER=dev
```

Here is the `docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
85c3123f93c8        postgres:9.5        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            lynx_postgres_1
```

When I try to connect from Intellij, below is the error:
[image]

Comment: `network_mode: host` generally disables Docker's networking.  It's not a standard configuration, and it's not usually necessary.  You should look at the Compose [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) setting as the standard way to get access to a service.

Comment: I got it to work by defining a network and putting both containers in that network

Answer (score 0):

It worked because by default custom network is in bridge mode.
The same thing as you use default to nothing.

Comment: can you explain more please